# Microsoft Q# : problems with rotate function R()

Tags: q#

Recently I've been working on algorithms of quantum computing where I faced some problems.

As there are probabilities for qubits to be observed as `|1>` or `|0>`, the rotation function is supposed to change the status of each qubit so that there can be more or fewer chances for them to be measured in a specific status.

In my program, I applied Hadamard transformation to a qubit and then rotated it with an angle θ(90°) in the z-axis, which was to make an equal probability of `|0>` and `|1>` measurement and then the rotation made the probs of status `|1> 100%`, but it didn't work anyway. The probs for `|1>` will always be 50% which is not supposed to be.

Here is my code:

```
operation Testing () : (Int)
{
    body
    {
        mutable result = -1;
        using (qubit = Qubit[1])
        {
            H(qubit[0]);
            R(PauliZ, PI() / -2.0, qubit[0]);

            //assertprob is a function to help test the probabilities of qubits in specific status
            AssertProb([PauliZ], qubit, One, 0.5,"Measuring in conjugate basis did not give 50/50 results.", 1e-5);
            //AssertProb([PauliZ], qubit, Zero, 0.5,"Measuring in conjugate basis did not give 50/50 results.", 1e-5);

            let value = M(qubit[0]);
            if(value == One)
            {
                set result = 1;
            } else {
                set result = 0;
            }
            ResetAll(qubit);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

A photo from [Microsoft Q# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/user-guide/?view=qsharp-preview) may help explain the sphere structure. After the Hadamard transformation, the qubit is in status `[1/√2,1/√2]` and then the rotation of `-π/2` makes it to status `[0,1]`.

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/media/concepts_bloch.png?view=qsharp-preview))</sub>

Comment: Next time, I advise to ask at https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying a rotation around the Pauli Z axis doesn't change the measurement probabilities of Z-axis measurements. You can visualize it this way:

- Your qubit's initial state is at +1 on the Z axis.
- The H operation moves it onto +1 on the X axis.
- Any rotation around the Z axis keeps the qubit's state in the X-Y plane, which is equally likely to measure as 0 or as 1 in the Z axis.

A pi/2 or 3pi/2 rotation around the Y axis will get the state back to the Z axis.

Comment: Oh my god! I understood now. Thank you so much! Maybe I should work on the spectral decomposition to understand more about rotaion.